# ArrayAdapter remove wrong?

Tags: android

When I run this code, I can freely add an object to the list.
However, when I try to change the bottom line to **cityAdapter.remove(newCity)**, this app does not response. What's the problem and how should I sovle that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA7QA.png)

Comment: Please include your code and logcat information

Comment: Hey @Dazhi Zhang Please include your code in written format and not with image also please include your logcat as well in written code format. Please have a look here once https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask